# Rails creating a simple function to run in console for system wide

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to do something as simple as:

```
rails c
> ping
=> pong
```

So I can write an action like:

def ping
     puts "pong"
end

But where do I put it? How do I make it work without having to instantiate a new model? application_helper.rb doesn't work, nor does application_controller.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you would like to run custom methods in Rails specifically, you can define you helper methods in a module in `lib` directory

```rb
# lib/custom_console_methods.rb

module CustomConsoleMethods
  def ping
    puts 'pong'
  end
end
```

Then in the `application.rb` file, pass a block to `console` that includes your module into `Rails::ConsoleMethods`

```rb
# config/application.rb

module YourRailsApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    console do
      require 'custom_console_methods'
      Rails::ConsoleMethods.include(CustomConsoleMethods)
    end
  end
end
```

If you would like to run it in system wide, just put the methods in `~/.irbrc` file. It gets loaded every time you run `irb` or `rails console`

```rb
def ping
  puts 'pong'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a folder `services` and in it you create a file `ping_service.rb`

```
class PingService
 def ping
  puts 'pong'
 end
end
```

and then in your console :

```
rails c
> PingService.new.ping
=> "pong"
```